# unable to catch2 hello test on mac running Apple LLVM version 10.0.1

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, catch2

Im only trying my tutorial to try catch2 unit testing lib. Im using mac with 10.14.
I dont have full XCode, only cmd tools and macports runs perfect in my setup (no brew).
Im using the amalgamated single header and source file as suggested.

Yet, a simple tutorial:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN  // This tells Catch to provide a main() - only do this in one cpp file
#include "catch.hpp"

unsigned int Factorial( unsigned int number ) {
    return number <= 1 ? number : Factorial(number-1)*number;
}


TEST_CASE( "Factorials are computed", "[factorial]" ) {
    REQUIRE( Factorial(1) == 1 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(2) == 2 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(3) == 6 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(10) == 3628800 );
}
```

gives many compile errors - snip:

```
In file included from test1.cpp:2:
./catch.hpp:75:49: warning: deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
            NonCopyable( NonCopyable const& ) = delete;
                                                ^
./catch.hpp:76:37: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
            NonCopyable( NonCopyable&& ) = delete;
                                    ^
./catch.hpp:76:44: warning: deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
            NonCopyable( NonCopyable&& ) = delete;
                                           ^
./catch.hpp:77:60: warning: deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
            NonCopyable& operator=( NonCopyable const& ) = delete;
                                                           ^
./catch.hpp:78:48: warning: rvalue references are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
            NonCopyable& operator=( NonCopyable&& ) = delete;
                                               ^
./catch.hpp:78:55: warning: deleted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
            NonCopyable& operator=( NonCopyable&& ) = delete;
                                                      ^
./catch.hpp:81:26: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
            NonCopyable() noexcept = default;
                         ^
                         ;
```

Please suggest, Thanks.

Edit:

After @Tiib suggested to try with `g++ -std=c++17` the code got compiled and build. `g++ -std=c++11` also did not work. Not understood why.

Comment: With what commands you try to compile your code? It seems that you are running the compiler in some pre C++11 mode and C++11 changed C++ syntax quite a bit indeed.

Comment: Just doing `gcc test1.cpp`.  Is there another way to build the tests?

Comment: Try gcc -std=c++11 test1.cpp

Comment: output is all same.

Comment: Hmm but clang++ -std=c++11 test1.cpp

Comment: Mine gcc is a alias of clang++.

Comment: Unsure then ... what does g++ --version tell you? Your toolset seems to be oddly outdated as it can't parse noexcept and warns about = delete even despite of -std=c++11

Comment: Apple LLVM version 10.0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232354/discussion-between-thevikas-and-oo-tiib).